# How to pass date parameter to query in temporary (work) table?

Tags: sas, 4gl

I wrote a few sas variables regarding dates. I also wrote a chunk of code `inc_mails` where I query db (using passthrough) and another chunk of code where I use temp table (work) to limit `inc_mails` to last month. When I pass `start_sas_month` and `end_sas_month` parameters to temp and run it then syntax error comes up (Error 22-322: syntax error). I don't know what's wrong.

My code below:

```
%let n_months = 1;

%let date = %sysfunc(date());

%let start_month = %sysfunc(intnx(month, &date., -&n_months.));
%let start_sas_month = %str(%')%sysfunc(putn(&start_month., date9.))%str(%'); %put &start_sas_month.;

%let end_month =  %sysfunc(intnx(day, %sysfunc(intnx(month, &date., 1-&n_months., b)), -1, s));
%let end_sas_month = %str(%')%sysfunc(putn(&end_month., date9.))%str(%'); %put &end_sas_month.;


proc sql;
connect to oracle as xyz (authdomain="XYZ_READ" path=XYZ_P);
create table work.inc_mails as 
select * from connection to xyz

(   
    SELECT 
    ap.Id,
    ap.Completed_Date

    FROM xy.Appointments ap
); 

disconnect from xyz;
Quit;


proc sql;
CREATE TABLE final_tbl AS
SELECT
i.Id,
i.Completed_Date

FROM work.inc_mails i

WHERE 
i.Completed_Date >= &start_sas_month.
AND i.Completed_Date <= &end_sas_month.
;
quit;
```

Above is just a short example of my real code.

I expected to get proper result without any error where dataset limited by sas date would be returned.

Comment: Can you get the WHERE condition to work properly if you don't use macro variables?  If so them just make sure the macro variables contain the same text as what works without macro code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely there are two issues with your code.

First you are treating COMPLETED_DATE as a if it contained a character string by doing a comparison like:

```
Completed_Date >= '01FEB2024'
```

So if COMPLETED_DATE is a character string you won't get any syntax errors, but the comparison will not work properly is '02JAN2024' comes after '01FEB2024' when comparing strings.

If you wanted to treat COMPLETED_DATE as if is had DATE values you would need to either add a letter D so that you are comparing to a date value.

```
Completed_Date >= '01FEB2024'd
```

Or just just use the actual integer value SAS uses to store that date (which you stored in a different macro variable).

```
Completed_Date >= 23407
```

The other issue is that ORACLE generally does not have a DATE variable type.  Only DATETIME variable types.  So when you extracted the data from your ORACLE database into a SAS dataset the COMPLETED_DATE variable probably became a DATETIME value (number of seconds since 1960) instead of a DATE value (number of days since 1960).

You could just use the DATEPART() function to extract the number of days from the number of seconds.

```
WHERE datepart(i.Completed_Date) between &start_month and &end_month
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for your reply. My question is - how to add `'d` to macro variable? I did it this way: `%let end_sas_month = %str(%')%sysfunc(putn(&end_month., date9.))%str(%'d); %put &end_sas_month.;` but it throws me syntax error again. `Completed_Date` is date column. If I use integer : `Completed_Date >= 23407` it works but doesn't returns any rows.

Comment: If you defined macro variable X with `'01JAN2024'`, then a simple way to add a D is with another %LET statement.  `%let x=&x.d;` or just append the D where you need it in your code, `where date <= &x.d`.

Comment: If using the actual date values, like 23407, does not work then COMPLETED_DATE does not contain DATE values.  Perhaps it has DATETIME values instead? Those are stored in seconds, not days.  Are you querying a SAS dataset or are you using a connection to some external database?

Comment: It works now, I've figured it out. Thanks for replies!